# Iphone Alarm Notification with continous ringing

Tags: iphone, xcode

Hi I am trying to create an alarm application using localNotification but alarm is playing for 30 sec only. I have searched a lot but i have not got any solution to play the sound continously. But in inbuild iphone alarm the sound is playing continously. If any one knows kindly explain it to me how and how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only method is to use local Notifications or Push notifications..both allow sounds to be played for 30 seconds

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible - only through a private API which won't be allowed in the AppStore

Comment: Private API means,in what way? If you have time Kindly explain it. And Thak you for your response

Comment: Why you need that because after implementation your App will be rejected